# How to add secondary legend to JavaFX chart?

Tags: java, javafx, charts, kotlin, tornadofx

When adding a custom node (in my case another legend for a JavaFX chart) with

```
val newLegend = MyLegend()
newLegend.isVertical=true

val legend = lookupAll(".chart-legend").first()
```

The legends are cascaded (not a surprise) but at least I know that I can render it:
[image]

So to properly align them vertically one after another I've tried to add it to the parent instead:

```
legend.getParent().addChildIfPossible( newLegend)
```

But this renders the additional node incorrectly in the upper left corner as just some dots
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Can I access the parent container of the first legend in a more clever way?

Full example sources can be found [here](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kravis/blob/73a4b4a2ef2989f5ac6f93cb5d21b1a151b56679/src/test/kotlin/com/github/holgerbrandl/kravis/tornadofx/ColorGradient.kt#L62)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Node with class `.chart-legend` is infact a `com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend`, which in turn extends `TilePane`. If you don't want to deal with the layout constraints of the `TilePane`, just clear the children off of it, and add whatever layout container you want inside it. In this example I've added a `VBox` and three labels:

```
with (lookupAll(".chart-legend").first()) {
    getChildList()?.clear()
    vbox {
        label("Line 1")
        label("Line 2")
        label("Line 3")
    }
}
```

Since it's clear that the chart doesn't really provide a convenient way for you to manipulate the legend, you could consider creating your own skin for the chart as a more stable solution. That way you can control exactly where the legend is displayed.

Comment: thanks. I would triple-accept if possible on SO, because it perfectly answers the question, the solution is in written kotlin, and is even using your great tornadofx api.

Comment: Happy to help :)